# Pandas. Replace NAN values according to variable distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I need to replace nan values in a column considering the distribution. The normalized frequency of the values are 0.5879336282383848, 0.37367433995536975 and 0.03839203180624546.
I was going to do something like:

```
for idx in nan_cols:
    if random() < 0.03839203180624546:
         df[idx][col] = 0
    elif random() < 0.03839203180624546 + 0.37367433995536975:
         df[idx][col] = 1
    else:
         df[idx][col] = 2
```

I'm thinking there must be some pandas's method or something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the question, you have a DataFrame containing some null data which you want to replace with values distributed in some known way.

The following approach, which utilises the `DataFrame.stack` and `DataFrame.unstack` methods, together with `pd.cut`, does what you want.

First, generate some dummy data representing your problem (here we have a 10x3 DataFrame populated by random data with `np.nan` values inserted at random locations):

```
_nr, _nc = 10, 3
_rnd = np.random.random((_nr, _nc))
_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col{}'.format(x) for x in range(_nc)], data=_rnd)
_stacked = _data.stack()
_nullidx = np.random.randint(0, _stacked.size-1, int(.80*_stacked.size))
_stacked.iloc[_nullidx] = np.nan
data = _stacked.unstack()
```

This generates something like the following:

```
print(data)

       col0      col1      col2
0  0.415485       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN  0.799004
2       NaN  0.359693       NaN
3       NaN       NaN  0.536442
4  0.733635       NaN       NaN
5       NaN       NaN       NaN
6  0.574215       NaN       NaN
7       NaN  0.949404       NaN
8       NaN  0.384289  0.633768
9  0.607698  0.266648  0.639140
```

What we want to do is populate these `np.nan` values with either 0, 1 or 2, depending on draws from a uniform distribution on [0,1] with respect to the following frequencies:

```
freqs = 0.03839203180624546, 0.37367433995536975, 0.5879336282383848
```

To achieve this we stack, cut and then unstack:

```
stacked = data.copy().stack(dropna=False)
stacked[stacked.isnull()] = \
            pd.cut(np.random.random(stacked.isnull().sum()), 
                   np.cumsum(np.insert(freqs,0,0.)), labels=(0,1,2))
result = stacked.unstack()
```

This gives:

```
print(result)

       col0      col1      col2
0  0.415485  2.000000  2.000000
1  2.000000  2.000000  0.799004
2  1.000000  0.359693  2.000000
3  1.000000  2.000000  0.536442
4  0.733635  0.000000  1.000000
5  2.000000  2.000000  2.000000
6  0.574215  2.000000  2.000000
7  1.000000  0.949404  2.000000
8  2.000000  0.384289  0.633768
9  0.607698  0.266648  0.639140
```